# Any Open Source / free ETL out there?

Tags: etl

I was using Pentaho Data Integration even before Pentaho bought it and call it that.
I have the last free version.

I went on their website recently to see if they had released another version only to find out my favorite open source etl is not much open anymore and not quite free.

Does any of you know of alternatives in affordable, easy to use ETL tools?

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of question [Open Source Business Intelligence/DWH solutions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/open-source-business-intelligence-dwh-solutions). You will find there your answers.

Comment: @Marian > The accepted answer in the question you are referring is Pentaho Data Integration.

I do ask for open source but also free and alternative to PDI.

I don't think that this question is a duplicate.

Comment: The tools are free. THe linked question was asked by me. There are professional versions (with features like 24/7 support and so on) and the community edition that the professional version is based on. So the version if completely free and you still have the features you would expect.

Comment: Jaspersoft etl ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Isn't [Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/) (Pentaho Data Integration Community Edition) still available without licensing fees?

Kettle 4.1 was released to the community as a stable release in fourth quarter of 2010. The community is currently working on a minor patch release to 4.1. Kettle continues to be a community supported product. Kettle may be a more appropriate tool in your sandbox or development environments.

However, in a production environment you may find that PDI Enterprise Edition with technical support from Pentaho more appropriate for your mission critical systems.

After discussion in comments below:
 Pentaho Data Integration (PDI - ak "Kettle") is still maintained (4.4 was release 2012-09) and Open Source. It can be downloaded from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration

Comment: Hi @RobPaller ~ Can you give any more information about why this would be an appropriate tool? Linking is nice, but giving concrete explanations is better ;)

Comment: the version I use is Kettle - Spoon Community Edition - 4.0.1.

I checked on Pentaho's website and what I see is PDI (aka Kettle) 30 days trial only.

That's what triggered my question. My concern is that Kettle is not maintained anymore and therefore I need to look for something else.

Comment: @ndefontenay (a bit late, but...) Pentaho Data Integration (PDI - ak "Kettle") is still maintained (4.4 was release 2012-09) and Open Source. It can be downloaded from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/

Comment: This is great news! I wonder if I can change the correct answer actually... Let's see.

Comment: Yup. That works.

Answer (score 17):

You could take a look at [Talend Open Studio](http://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio). The development environment runs inside of Eclipse, and there are many different kinds of database connectors & transformations. Also, given that it is an open source project, you can build your own connectors & transformations to share with other users (even commercial users) of Talend.

Comment: Hi @NWest ~ Can you give any more information about why this would be an appropriate tool? Linking is nice, but giving concrete explanations is better ;)

Comment: I found Talend a little difficult to learn and slow against huge datasets, but, pretty helpful overall.

Comment: I knew there was another player in this arena. Talend slipped my mind.

Comment: I will definitely have a look :)

Comment: Btw, what is the scripting language used by talend open studio ?

Answer (score 6):

This is more developer-centric than DBA centric, but I've heard good things about Rhino ETL.
https://github.com/ayende/rhino-etl

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used it because I use SSIS for my ETL needs, but have you checked out [expressor Studio](http://www.expressor-software.com/studio.htm)?

You could also check out [ReactiveETL](http://reactiveetl.codeplex.com/) which is a rewrite of RhinoETL on CodePlex

If you are in an environment that is using SQL Server, you should have access to SSIS which is included with SQL Server and is able to attach to other databases using OLEDB or ODBC connections, so it doesn't have to be connecting to SQL Server in order to use it.

There have even been some presentations on using Powershell for ETL, one such presentation was put on by the App Dev Virtual Chapter of PASS.

For more details on that presentation check out the following link:

http://sev17.com/2010/06/22/powershell-etl-presentation/

Answer (score 1):

I played with [Aptar](http://www.apatar.com/) a bit a number of years ago.  I can't say how well they've stood the test of time, though.

Answer (score 1):

A few more...

- [CloverETL](http://www.cloveretl.com/)
- [Konstanz Information Miner (KNIME)](http://www.knime.org/)
- [SpagoBI](http://www.spagoworld.org/xwiki/bin/view/SpagoBI/)

Comment: MacGyver - Do you have experience with any of these?  Can you update the answer with some pros and cons?

Comment: I haven't yet.  I'm researching the tools out there for data warehousing and trying to choose one, so I'll include some more details once I have them organized.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do [Mirth Connect](http://www.mirthcorp.com/products/mirth-connect) might be suitable, though it is more of a messaging engine than an ETL tool.

Comment: Are you affiliated with them in any way?

Comment: I'm not, I've just been looking at it for Health XML Messaging and it seemed as if it might have wider applications. It certainly feels more polished than Pentaho.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Usually, when recommending commercial tools, it is advisable to make your (non)-affiliation clear, this is why I asked.

Comment: Just to point out, Mirth Connect is open source.